# MultipleChoiceField with SelectMultiple widget "Value [...] not a valid choice."

Tags: django, forms, select, django-models, field

I have a field defined in my model-

```
    languages = models.CharField(max_length = 30, choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICES, blank = True, null = True)
```

The choices are simple-

```
LANGUAGE_CHOICES = (
    ('English', 'English'),
)
```

I define a ModelForm on this model and override the field-

```
languages = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICES, widget=forms.SelectMultiple)
```

When I fill out the form, select "English", and try to submit, I get an error-

languages
Value u"[u'English']" is not a valid choice

Is there something basic that I am doing wrong? Or is the MultipleChoiceField combined with the SelectMultiple widget not the way to go?

Also, is there any reason why the choices tuple can't have the same value twice, like I have it now ('English', 'English')?

**Here is some additional code that might be useful in getting to the bottom of this**

Template Code:

```
<div class="abovepad">
<label for="id_languages">Languages:</label>
    {{form.languages}}
</div>
```

The portion of POST data with the languages:

```
u'languages': [u'English'],
```

Relevant snippet of ModelForm code:

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):        
languages = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICES)
class Meta:
    model = Student
```

As you see, I barely customized anything. In the past when I ran into this issue I would switch to making the items in the list to models and then using ManyToMany fields which did not cause the same issue. For those instances, having the items be models made sense; in this case it doesn't. I just want to know whether I'm doing something wrong or whether this combo is not supposed to work. If there's no real answer then my other option would be to try and dig through the Django form code to see why its doing what its doing.

Answer (score 9):

You must remove `choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICES` from your *model* *definition*:
what your form return is the list of selected value, that doesn't exist in your `models.LANGUAGE_CHOICES`

Comment: I'm surprised this answer hasn't received the attention that it should have. I encountered the exact same problem as OP and this answer is what saved me hours of debugging !

Answer (score 2):

I know this over a year old now but thought it may still be helpful to attempt an answer.

I believe there may be a couple of issues here, but the main issue at hand is that the ModelForm is expecting a key to the database record not a string value.

I would suggest making a Form instead of ModelForm, if you are making a form that isn't relating to your database. But if you do want to interact with your database then use the ModelForm and and define a ForeignKey in your Student model to relate to the language table, letting the ModelForm do the work for you.

Example app based on my assumptions of your model.

*`your_project/example_app/models.py:`*

```
from django.db import models

class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    language = models.ForeignKey('Language')

class Language(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

*`your_project/example_app/forms.py:`*

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from example.models import Student

class StudentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
```

Relevant docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform

snippet:

> As you might expect, the ForeignKey and ManyToManyField model field types are special cases:
>
> ForeignKey is represented by `django.forms.ModelChoiceField`, which is a ChoiceField whose choices are a model QuerySet.
>   ManyToManyField is represented by `django.forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField`, which is a MultipleChoiceField whose choices are a model QuerySet.

Comment: +1 For the snippet from the docs which helped me resolve an unrelated issue due to accidentally using `ModelChoiceField` instead of `ModelMultipleChoiceField` on a `ManyToManyField`.

Answer (score 1):

The error message suggests that instead of containing an array, `languages` contains a unicode string containing a representation of that array. `languages` should evaluate to `[u'English']` (array) but instead evaluates to `u"[u'English']"` (unicode string).

Does your ModelForm include any custom validation (say, a `clean_languages` function) that might be changing the value for `languages`?

BTW: `SelectMultiple` is already the default widget for `MultipleChoiceField` so there's no need to specify the widget.

Some things that would be useful for finding the cause:

- the template code that renders the form
- the `POST` data returned by the form
- the code used for your ModelForm class

Comment: Thanks Jordan, for your prompt response. I posted the relevant piece of info above. My ModelForm does not include anything extra, and getting rid of the explicit widget parameter unfortunately doesn't help. Seems to me that the Django form validation code for some reason takes the array in the POST data and converts it to a string...